# hookActionOrderSlipAdd() finding id_order_slip

Tags: php, prestashop

Im building a module that uses the hook `hookActionOrderSlipAdd();`. In The parameters there seems to be no way to obtain the id_order_slip that is required for building the `new orderSlip($id_order_slip);`

The only way I see now is using a database query to look up all the credit slips with an order and selecting the last one. Which does not seem very neat. Can someone point me in the right direction?

The start of my hook:

```
public function hookActionOrderSlipAdd($params){

    $post = Tools::getAllValues();

    ppp($post);
    ppp($params);

    $id_order_slip = '????';

    $order_slip = new OrderSlip($id_order_slip);
    ppp($order_slip);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code.

```
public function hookActionOrderSlipAdd($params)
{    
    $order_slips = OrderSlip::getOrdersSlip((int)$params['order']->id_customer, (int)$params['order']->id);

    foreach ($order_slips as $order_slip_details)
    {
        $order_slip = new OrderSlip((int)$order_slip_details['id_order_slip']);
        /* Your actions. */
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, smart solution. I only needed the last, currently added slip. Solved like this:
        `$orderSlips = OrderSlip::getOrdersSlip((int)$params['order']->id_customer, (int)$params['order']->id);
        $orderSlip = $orderSlips[key( array_slice( $orderSlips , 0, 1, TRUE ) )];
        $orderSlip = new OrderSlip($orderSlip['id_order_slip']);`